# How can I make a row that is 100% parent width that has 2 children where the second child is positioned on the center of the screen width

Tags: flutter

If I have a row that has 2 children. How can I make it so that the row takes up 100% of its parent's width and the second child is positioned in the center of that row? So at 50% of its parent's width. This is what I have so far but now both children align left of the row. I want settings to be in the center of that row.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: 
          [ 
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Row
              (
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: NavigatePopButton(),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Align
                  (
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Text
                    (
                      'Settings',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                ],
              )
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                context: context,
                removeTop: true,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: 3,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1.0), 
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Setting ' + index.toString()),
                      );
                  }       
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[This is what it look right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIKYl.png)

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqG2M.jpg)

Comment: a sample image of what is the result that you want would be helpful.

Comment: Added the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqG2M.jpg) you provided. Why even use Row, why not try this

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: NavigatePopButton(),
      ),
      Align
      (
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Text
        (
          'Settings',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: When I try to make it a stack I get an error that the parent cannot be a expanded why is this?

Comment: Nevermind! It forgot to remove the Spacers! This is the correct answer!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Use the `Expanded` widgets on the row items, this will force them to use the max width.

set the second child's alignment to also be `top left`

```
Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft, // set this to left
              child: Text(
                'Settings',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

#### References

- [Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

Comment: This produces a result when both expanded take 50% of the screen width an aligning  where settings is starts on the right half of the screen. I would like for settings to be exactly in the middle of the row

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [Spacers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) around your text.

```dart
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: NavigatePopButton(),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      Align
      (
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Text
        (
          'Settings',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),
    ],
  )
```